# Connect to Saved Wifi Network with nmcli (network-manager command line interface)

Tags: wireless-networking, networkmanager

In a Linux desktop environment network-manager has a saved wireless network that I connect to manually by clicking the *Connect* button in the GUI. (It is set intentionally to *not* automatically connect to this particular wifi network)

I want to achieve the same thing as clicking the *Connect* button, **from the terminal**; (eg, using `nmcli`)

This is how far I've gotten

```
nmcli con up "ManualNetworkName"
Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network 'ManualNetworkName'.
Warning: password for '802-11-wireless-security.psk' not given in 'passwd-file' and nmcli cannot ask without '--ask' option.
```

Why is it giving this error about not finding the password in some password file?

Network-manager already has the password saved for this network. In the GUI I literally only need to click the *Connect* button, and it connects with no further interaction. I do not have to enter a password, because it's already saved for this wifi network in network-manager. The network-manager GUI works as expected.

BTW I will not accept an answer that involves specifying a password to connect via the terminal. It MUST use the existing network-manager profile to connect (that includes various settings for this network; not only a password).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that doing exactly what you have posted works for me on Linux Mint 19 Tara :-(

The only things I can think of are:

- check that there isn't a problem with the command you are running. `nmcli con up "ManualNetworkName"` works on my system but the man page says it's `nmcli c up "ManualNetworkName"` 'c' rather than 'con'
- check you aren't running the command as a different user i.e. root or some other user that doesn't have access to your keyring.
- (a long shot) check that your keyring has actually been opened. i.e. test that you can click on the button in the gui to connect and disconnect then go to a terminal and try to do the same thing with commands. (You've probably already done that though)

> **Note:** I'm fairly sure that nmcli saves passwords in
>   `~/.local/share/keyrings/` but of course these files are encrypted and
>   so need to be opened by `seahorse` (which is the commandline name for
>   "Passwords and Keys")